# SCP stalls at `sending command -v -t .`

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am trying to send a file from my computer to a server using the following command:

```
scp -v file.txt username@server:~/file.txt
```

- I used my username and the real server address in the above command.

And here's the log after entering the password:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to `server` ([`server_ip`]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t ~/file.txt
```

Comment: can you `ssh` on the server? How does the server debug log look like?

Comment: @Jakuje Yes I can easily SSH to the server. But SCP doesn't work...

Comment: What do you have in your `~/.bashrc` and similar startup scripts on the server?

Comment: @Jakuje Only two lines of code. First one loads a Python module, second loads TMUX
`module load LANG/PYTHON/2.7.6` and `module load TOOLS/TMUX/2.1`

Comment: Absolutely nothing I've tried has worked :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `~/.bashrc`, which might interfere with the remote commands (such as `scp`).

```
module load LANG/PYTHON/2.7.6
module load TOOLS/TMUX/2.1
```

If you want to do something like this, you should do it only on interactive shells (not to break scripts). You can add to the start of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: Thanks. What does `[-z "$PS1"]` do?

Comment: It is a test, that the variable `PS1` is empty, which is usually for noninteractive shells/commands.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same symptoms when trying to scp but the cause was this option in my .ssh/config on the client:

```
RequestTTY force
```

Commenting that out made scp work.